# Synchronize two highstock charts, same rangeSelector across two tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, highcharts

```
No code to this question.
```

Please see my jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MrSnrub/w8rem1be/

I have two Highstock (Highcharts) charts, one on each jQuery UI tab. I want the two charts to have synchronized rangeSelectors, navigators, and scrollbars. In other words, changing one results in the same change in the other. If the navigator of the "Stock Prices" chart is moved, then the navigator for the "Percentage Change" chart will be changed accordingly, and the two should never go out of sync. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case if someone is looking for the solution - I have answered the question on Highcharts forum: [click](http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/cannot-get-two-highcharts-to-sync-using-aftersetextremes-t36203/)

Quick summary:

1. Synchronising navigator and scrollbar can be achieved by getting and setting extremes

   ```
   ex = oldChart.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
   newChart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(ex.min, ex.max, true, false);
   ```
2. Synchronising rangeSelector can be achieved by manipulating buttons' states

   ```
   var newRangeSelector = newChart.rangeSelector,
       newSelected = newRangeSelector.selected,
       oldSelected = oldChart.rangeSelector.selected;

   if (newSelected !== null) {
       newRangeSelector.buttons[newSelected].setState(0);
   }

   if (oldSelected !== null) {
       newRangeSelector.buttons[oldSelected].setState(2);
       newRangeSelector.setSelected(oldSelected);
   }
   ```
3. There is no need to keep a hidden chart always update - first reason is better performance, second there are some bugs in calculation positions of the items on hidden DOM elements - so the chart should be updated when the relevant tab is activated - it can be achieved by setting callback in jquery tabs activate event.

   ```
   $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
       activate: function (e, ui) { }
   )};
   ```

Full example: https://jsfiddle.net/w8rem1be/35/